# Webpack breaks code with anonymous function when and webpack duplicating function calls

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, import, webpack-dev-server

I am having a big fight with my dear friend Webpack today. I have tried this code on a non-webpacked script page to know it works. Now that I have added my code to webpack it's displaying strange behavior.

1. It is looping the function call of `listmodule` over & over until it fills the page with the content that the function brings up.
2. The code outright breaks during the first call of `displayRadioValue`. Specifically as it's going through ele.length. The chrome dev tools window suddenly switches at that point to an anonymous function that wasn't hardcoded by me (by webpack I assume) and continues on a divergent line of anonymous function calls but never finishes the `resetModule` code that called `displayRadioValue` in the first place.

Here is my webpack config

```
    `const path = require('path');
    const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
    
    module.exports = {
      entry: {
        index:  './src/index.js',
        modules: './src/modules.js',
        utility: './src/utility.js',
      },
      plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
          title: 'toDoList',
          template: 'dist\\index.html'
        }),
      ], 
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
      mode: "development",
      output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true,
      },
      optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
            type: 'asset/resource',
          },
        ],
      },
     };`
```

Here is my package.json

```
  {
      "name": "odintodo",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "build": "webpack"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
        "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
        "webpack": "^5.75.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.0.0"
      }
    }
```

Lastly here is the file that's causing the issue so far. I can post the other two js files if needed for context.

```
import { Task } from './index.js'
import { displayRadioValue } from './utility.js'
import { ToDoList } from './index.js'
import { saveToLocalStorage } from './utility.js'
import { updateMainscreen } from './utility.js'
import { updateSubscreen } from './utility.js'
import { updateSidebar } from './utility.js'
import './styles.css'
const newListButton = document.getElementById("newL")
const schedule = [] 
const mover = document.getElementById("mover")
const display = document.getElementById("display")
export const listModule = () => { 
    mover.remove(newListButton)
    var newLocal =`<form class="entryForm" action="#" method="post">
        <h4>Create A tasklist</h4>
        <label for="title">List title:</label>
        <input type="text" id="listName" name="List Title" placeholder="Insert Tasklist title here"><br>
        <button id="submitList">Submit List</button>
        </form>`
    display.innerHTML += newLocal
    var submitListButton = document.getElementById("submitList")
    submitListButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        taskModule()
    })
return {listModule}
}
export const taskModule = () => {
    var listName = document.getElementById("listName").value
    display.innerHTML = " "
    var newLocal = `<form class="entryForm" action="#" method="post">
            <h2>Create a task</h2>
            <label for="Task Name">Task Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="taskName" name="task Name" placeholder="Insert Task Name Here"><br>
            <label for="taskDescription">Task description</label>
            <input type="text" id="description" name="taskDescription" placeholder="task description here"><br>
            <label for="dueDate">Due date</label>
            <input type="text" id="dueDate" name="dueDate" placeholder="Insert due date here"><br>
            <label for="priority">Priorty:</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="priority" name="priority" value="High" ><label for="priority">High</label>
            <input type="radio" id="priority" name="priority" value="Medium"><label for="priority">Medium</label>
            <input type="radio" id="priority" name="priority" value="Low"><label for="priority">Low</label>
            <button id="submitTask">Submit</button>
            </form>`
    display.innerHTML += newLocal
    var submitTaskButton = document.getElementById("submitTask")
    submitTaskButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        resetModule(listName)
    })

    return {listName}, {taskModule}
}
const resetModule = (listName) => {
    let priority = displayRadioValue()
    var title = document.getElementById("taskName").value
    var description = document.getElementById("description").value
    var dueDate = document.getElementById("dueDate").value
    display.innerHTML = " "
    let newTask  = new Task(title, description, dueDate, priority)
    saveToLocalStorage(listName, newTask)
    var activeList = null
    for (const list of schedule) {
        if (list.listName === listName) {
            activeList = list
        }
    }
    // If a ToDoList with the same name was not found, create a new one
    if (activeList === null) {
        activeList = new ToDoList(listName)
        saveToLocalStorage(listName, list)
        schedule.push(activeList)
    }
    activeList.addTask(newTask)
    mover.appendChild(newListButton)
    updateSidebar(newTask, activeList)
    updateMainscreen(activeList, newTask)
    updateSubscreen(newTask)
    return {resetModule}, {schedule}
}
```

Comment: Your code is pretty weird, what are you trying to achieve by returning `{listModule}` from `listModule` itself?

Comment: And similarly, `return {listName}, {taskModule}` is pretty nonsensical, or in any case it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: There was a lot of experimentation that needs to be cleaned up so I do apologize for it not being easy on the eyes at the moment but the issue here is webpack since the code actually does run as intended without it

Comment: But this is exactly the kind of thing that could make webpack very confused and cause the behavior that you are observing, that's why I'm mentioning it.